# Как сделать через PHP или JS, чтобы URL принимал другое значение

Tags: php, javascript

Как сделать через PHP или JS, чтобы **URL** принимал другое значение. Как в соц.сетях у пользователя. Например:

http://hagok.ru/index.php?view=user&id=213&users=vasiliy/
превратить в:
http://hagok.ru/vasiliy

то есть "index.php?view=user&id=213&users=vasiliy" превратить в "vasiliy".

спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

[mod_rewrite](https://www.google.ru/search?q=mod_rewrite+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B&oq=mod_rewrite+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.4994j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fp=9dd89a98d12b632&q=mod_rewrite+) изучайте, примеры [тут](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=309).

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Да елки палки. Бред это все. Те люди, которые пользуются апачевским mod_rewrite, и думают, что все так делают - вас обманули.

Решение: берете фреймворк(любой), пусть даже микрофреймворк (как Flask для python), и там у вас из коробки будут не только url`ы, но и плюшки в виде MVC (MVT, MVVM etc.).

После php это покажется вам райским решением, и назад вы уже не вернетесь. А если и вернетесь, то будете писать более правильно структурированные сайты, и меньше говнокодить.